# What is the correct intuitive definition of a Pauli spinor?

Tags: vectors, spinors

A **Euclidean 3d vector** is a quantity with a magnitude and a direction.
It has three components along the three coordinate axes. The three components point along the three coordinate axes. A vector can be defined with two angles that specify the direction, and one real number that specifies the magnitude.

What is the best intuitive definition of a Pauli spinor (in 3d)? More concretely, what has to be amended in the following definition, to make it correct:

A **Pauli spinor** is a quantity with a magnitude and a direction.
It has three components along the three coordinate axes. The three components are rotations along the three coordinate axes. A Pauli spinor can be imagined as two angles that specify its direction, and a third angle that specifies its rotation *around* that direction.

P.S. Does a Pauli spinor have three or four real parameters? If there are four, how should the definition be amended?

Comment: https://archive.org/details/OperaMagistris/page/n1640/mode/1up?view=theater     (finally an English translation) , display takes time (+-10s) due to number of pages >8200....
For more details: The theory of spinors
by Cartan, Elie.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have to start by narrowing the scope of your question. I am specifically not talking about the position dependence. For example, your electron would have a radial and angular dependent wavefunction part, and I am ignoring all of that. Note that this is highly non-trivial, because, say, for the Dirac electron, even for plane waves, all 4 components, that we typically interpret as spin up and down electron parts and spin up and down positron parts, get intertwined together.

So you can think of my answer as, say, the purely spinor part of a Hydrogen atom ground state electron, or of an ideal plane wave, etc.

I am also going to have to assume that you are not going to throw a wrench into the standard QFT, Wigner style alignment of the frame of reference everywhere in the universe, that a stationary electron thus excited into existence would be spin up and uniformly everywhere in the universe. After all, what spinors really mean, is best understood from Wigner's and Weyl's construction of them all.

---

Then we can start with an immediate misconception. A Euclidean 3D vector has 3 real components. The Pauli spinor that seems to live in our 3D space, actually only has 2 real components. The generic unit vector is conventionally given by
$$\tag1\hat{\vec n}=
\begin{pmatrix}\sin\vartheta\cos\varphi\\\sin\vartheta\sin\varphi\\\cos\vartheta
\end  {pmatrix}\qquad\implies\qquad\hat{\vec n}\cdot\vec{\hat\sigma}=
\begin{pmatrix}
+\cos\vartheta&e^{-i\varphi}\sin\vartheta\\
e^{+i\varphi}\sin\vartheta&-\cos\vartheta
\end  {pmatrix}$$
The spin up and down eigenspinors of this spinor operator at arbitrary direction are
$$\tag2\left|+\hat{\vec n}\right>=
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-i\frac\varphi2}\cos\frac\vartheta2\\e^{+i\frac\varphi2}\sin\frac\vartheta2
\end  {pmatrix}\qquad\bigwedge\qquad\left|-\hat{\vec n}\right>=
\begin{pmatrix}
-e^{-i\frac\varphi2}\sin\frac\vartheta2\\e^{+i\frac\varphi2}\cos\frac\vartheta2
\end  {pmatrix}$$
I leave it to you to easily substitute and verify that these are indeed the eigenspinors.

It is manifestly clear from the above presentation that the normalised Pauli spinors actually only have 2 real components, basically being the latitude and longitude. It even has the loss of one real component at the poles.

Note, however, that spinors are a double-cover, and thus the negative of a spinor is identified with a spinor. It is important to get this correct, because it is necessary to get this baked into the mathematics. After all, we can do a passive full rotation any time we want, and the physics must stay the same.

---

We thus come to a point where we chat about the intuitive understanding of what it is we have come to. To the folk that are all gung-ho about ``shut up and calculate", just getting the mathematics correct is all that matters, and we should not be asking about what more these things can mean, outside of what the mathematics requires them to be.

But I want to *chat about non-mainstream views* for a bit, since the main gist is already covered.

One thing to note about the spinors, is the appearance of all the half angles, and that negation is almost the same as identity. The natural mathematical entity that also has this behaviour in the classical regime, is in the rotors of geometric algebra. When Hamilton discovered quaternions, after some time, he discovered that the correct way to do rotation in higher maths is not by a single sided rotation matrix, but rather by
$$\tag3R^{-1}\vec xR$$
where $R$ is a rotor. With non-commutativity, it is very easy to understand that the old complex number rotation scheme of $\vec xe^{i\varphi}$ really should have been $e^{-i\varphi/2}\vec xe^{+i\varphi/2},$ and not only is this very easy to prove to be equivalent, it is also the correct way to generalise this to arbitrarily many dimensions.

Now, when you look at how quantum wavefunctions are used in the Dirac scheme, you see all the $\bar\psi\gamma\psi,$ and this is really just the same thing. It is thus not a big leap of faith to view the spinor part has enacting a rotation of the gamma matrices, if you think of the gamma matrices as a frame of reference, with one pointing in the observer's time coördinate, and then each one of the $x,y,z$ axes.

It is thus somewhat nice to think of spinors as bivector, rotors, that enact the same thing as rotors do to vectors in classical 3D space. It is not new maths, but just not the current standard physics and maths view.

But beware, normal physics does not do this.

Comment: Following Steane's notes, a spinor has four parameters: https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/~Steane/teaching/rel_C_spinors.pdf
3 rotation angles and 1 length.

Comment: One of the "rotation angle" is an overall phase shift, that has no meaning even in quantum theory. The magnitude is a problem that ought to be solved with the position / momentum wavefunction, and thus should also not be included with the spinor part alone.

Comment: Hm, but if the overall phase changes over space, as Feynman tells, then it does play a role.

Comment: Again, that is the wavefunction part, not the spinor part.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for an answer. This is the best I found.

In Steane's textbook, a Pauli spinor is defined as a flagpole and a sign.
The flagpole has a length, two angles that define the direction of the pole, one angle specifying the orientation of the flag around the pole, and a sign.

So, a Pauli spinor has 4 real parameters and a sign.